# Showing an analytic function is constant under certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a homework question from Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*, and I'm confused as to how to begin. The question is:

> If $f(z)$ is analytic in the whole plane, and if $z^{-1}\mbox{Re}f(z) \to 0$ when $z \to \infty$, show that f is a constant.

The book gives the hint to use $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{\zeta + z}{\zeta - z}u(\zeta)\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta} + iC $$

However, I'm not really sure how this helps. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hint: compute $f'(0)$ by differentiating the integral in $z$ and letting then $z=0$; if you do it correctly, you will see that the given estimate for $u$ immediately implies $f'(0)=0$ when you let $R \to \infty$; repeat same for any higher derivative and get that $f''(0)=0,...f^{(n)}(0)=0,...$ and conclude

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard way to estimate integrals to find a bound for $|f'(z)|$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, where the $f'(z)$ is found by taking the derivative inside the integral and the hypothesis tells you that $|\frac{u(\zeta)}{\zeta}|$ is bounded. As a consequence you have $f(z)=a+bz$, but using the hypothesis again you get $b=0$.